# Express como fazer uma div aparecer apenas se o usuário estiver logado?

Tags: node.js, back-end

Bom, acabei de fazer o cadastro no meu site e gostaria que quando o usuário logasse os links de login e cadastro sumissem e no lugar aparece uma div com um drop menu mostrando links para minha conta, logout etc.
O que devo usar nessa div? Estou usando express 4, passport e ejs.

Comment: Tente usar [variáveis locais](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/4x/api.html#res.locals) para uma verificação uma vez que esta usando passport e renderizando com ejs

Answer (score 3):

O `passport` adiciona uma propriedade `.user` ao `request` e costuma ter uma função assim:

```
function gateKeeper(req, res, next){
    let environment = express().get('env');
    if (req.user) next();
    else res.redirect('/login');
}
```

Assim, se o `req.user` estiver definido sabes que o utilizador está logado.

Comment: Consigo pegar o usuário logado agora, mas acredito que estou errando em outro ponto

Comment: @BrunoMaia podes juntar o código onde chamas o .render()/template do ejs?

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo o que vc disse, estou usando essa verificação para tentar esconder o cadastro e login quando o usuário estiver logado e no lugar colocar um menu drop, mas estou tendo um problema.
O cadastro e login ficam aparecendo sempre, logado ou não logado o que estou fazendo de errado?

```
<% if (this.user) { %>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span></button>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="/profile">Minha conta</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/painelControle">Meus eventos</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <% } else{ %>
                            <li><a href="/cadastroUsuario" class="linkscabecalho">Cadastro</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/login" class="linkscabecalho"> Login </a></li>
                            <% } %>
                                <li><a href="/criarEvento" class="linkscabecalho">Criar evento </a></li>
```